# Is there a way to hide a SELECT based on the value of another SELECT using only CSS?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I have 2 `SELECT` elements, but I only want to display the second if the first has a specific value.

I know how to do this with javascript, but I was hoping I could use an adjacent sibling selector to accomplish this with pure HTML/CSS:

```
<style>
  select[name=select2] { display:none; }
  select[value=show] + select[name=select2] { display:auto; }
</style>

<select name="select1">
  <option value="show">Show Select 2</option>
  <option value="hide">Hide Select 2</option>
</select>
<select name="select2">
</select>
```

Unfortunately, I can't get this to work. I imagine it's because `value` isn't a real attribute of a `SELECT`, but I'm not sure. Any ideas what is going on here?

Here's a fiddle to test with:
http://jsfiddle.net/rr24g/

Comment: As has already been said, this is indeed impossible with CSS.

Answer (score 4):

no, totally impossible, because css is "cascading" you can't go upwards

```
/* pseudo code - doesn't work, just demonstrating the problem */
select[name=select1] > option[value=show][selected] ::parent:: + select[name=select2]
```

you need javascript!

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to say "No".  You're coding UI based on business logic specifically.  CSS wasn't designed for that.  Keep it in javascript.

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to do something with `:hover` using the top level `select`s.

Otherwise, I think a js solution is in order.